# Rails rspec-guard runs multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

I've just updated my rspec and guard installations because guard ran 3 times on every change after I started it with `bundle exec guard`. Well, now it runs 5 times whenever I change something in my code.

This is the terminal output message I get when running `bundle exec guard`

```
10:45:30 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
10:45:30 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
10:45:30 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
10:45:30 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
10:45:30 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
10:45:30 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
10:45:30 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/me/myProject'
10:45:38 - INFO - Running: spec/features/admin_area_spec.rb
```

I think there maybe is some place where the listener or something else gets started five times but I couldn't find it.

**Update**
I'm using `guard-rspec-4.2.8`, `rspec-2.14.1` and `guard-2.5.1`.

Comment: what versions of RSpec, guard and guard-rspec are you using? If you could provide a sample application with the bug present you could then create a ticket on guard-rspec.

Comment: I updated the question with additional infos. Well it's an app which already is in production, so it's not so easy to extract a part of it for example purpose. Would the rspec/guard config files be sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found out that I had the guard startup code multiple times in the guardfile. Removing all of them but one fixed the issue.

Comment: Like where? I'm running guard with `bundle exec guard --group fast_tests,lints --wait-for-delay 1`